# Why is delta time not working? (MonoGame, C#)

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to make my game use delta time so it becomes independent of FPS. I had a go at doing it and compared them side-by-side:

https://youtu.be/XYC-AZbk0JE

But the player on the 144fps one still goes faster. My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace _2D_Game_Test.GameStates
{
public class TestState : GameState
{
    Vector2 velocity;
    Vector2 position;

    double change = 0;

    KeyboardState keyboardState;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        position = new Vector2((1280 / 2) - (Game.Bob.Width / 2), (720 / 2) - (Game.Bob.Height / 2));
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            change = 0;
            velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            position = new Vector2((1280 / 2) - (Game.Bob.Width / 2), (720 / 2) - (Game.Bob.Height / 2));
        }

        double delta = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            if (change > 0)
            {
                change -= (10 * delta);
            }
            else if (change > -5f)
            {
                if (change - (5 * delta) < -5f)
                {
                    change = -5f;
                }
                else
                {
                    change -= (5 * delta);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            if (change < 0)
            {
                change += (10 * delta);
            }
            else if (change < 5f)
            {
                if (change + (5 * delta) > 5f)
                {
                    change = 5f;
                }
                else
                {
                    change += (5 * delta);
                }
            }
        }

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
        {
            if (change > 0)
            {
                if ((change -= (2 * delta)) < 0)
                {
                    change = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    change -= (2 * delta);
                }
            }
            else if (change < 0)
            {
                if ((change += (2 * delta)) > 0)
                {
                    change = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    change += (2 * delta);
                }
            }
        }

        velocity.X = (float)change;
        position += velocity;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Game.Bob, position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.Debug, "A and D up: " + (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.D)), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.Debug, "A down: " + (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)), new Vector2(10, 30), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.Debug, "D down: " + (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)), new Vector2(10, 50), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.Debug, "Velocity modifier: " + velocity, new Vector2(10, 70), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.Debug, "Current velocity: " + velocity.X, new Vector2(10, 90), Color.Black);
    }
}
}
```

What did I do wrong?

P.S: I'm positive it's not just my eyes playing with me. I can see the player going faster on 144fps than the one on 60fps.

Comment: Your image link doesnt work

Comment: Your velocity probably goes faster because update is called more often. Hard to tell

Comment: Your picture does not confirm your statement that velocity is gaining faster in the 144fps version as both sit at zero

Comment: Video added. It shows the player moving faster on 144fps even though I incorporate delta time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the delta time itself.

When you are calculating the velocity change, you are applying the delta time perfectly.

The problem comes when you actually apply the velocity to the player itselft. Let's say you are at max velocity (5). Since you don't take into account the delta time while applying the velocity to the position, you'll apply the velocity way more often at 144fps than at 60fps. That's why the character seem to go faster.

You probably want to do something like:

```
position += velocity * delta;
```

That should fix your problem.